# How to find the closest row depending on given percentage?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using Laravel and MySQL,
Supposing I have a percentage value not found between the two percentage columns (`percentage_from`, `percentage_to`), for example, if it's equal to 33, I need to get the closest percentage row which is the first row in this case, if it's 35 then the second row if it's 66 then the third row.

| type | attendance_from | attendance_to | payment_percentage | percentage_from | percentage_to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Monthly | 1 | 10 | 100 | 0 | 32.258064516129 |
| Monthly | 11 | 20 | 70 | 35.483870967742 | 64.516129032258 |
| Monthly | 21 | 31 | 50 | 67.741935483871 | 100 |

I tried this function:

```
public function getClosest(array $array, $value) {
    $closest = null;
    $res = null;
    foreach ($array as $item) {
        if ($closest === null || abs($value - $closest) > abs($item['percentage_to'] - $value)) {
            $closest = $item['percentage_to'];
            $res = $item;
        }
    }
    return $res;
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?

Comment: I fixed it using other way, I have eliminated the gap between the percentages columns, so if the first row ends with 32.25, then the second row will start from 32.25

Comment: Can you answer your own question so other people can benefit from it?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it in another way: I have eliminated the gap between the percentages columns, so if the first row ends with `32.25`, then the second row will start from `32.25`.

| type | attendance_from | attendance_to | payment_percentage | percentage_from | percentage_to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Monthly | 1 | 10 | 100 | 0 | 32.25 |
| Monthly | 11 | 20 | 70 | 32.25 | 64.51 |
| Monthly | 21 | 31 | 50 | 64.51 | 100 |

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).